# Nodejs and Expressjs sending ajax post request is not working

Tags: jquery, node.js

[image]I'm having a problem in sending post data in http://localhost:3000/users.I'm using Expressjs framework and mongoDB as my database. The main problem is when I inspect the ajax post method in browser, it is being skipped and nothing is happening.
Not sure what's going wrong

router.post in INDEX.js

```
router.post('/users', function(req, res) {
   var db = req.db;
   var users = db.get('orders');
   var sub_users = db.get('users');
   var col_name=req.query.colname;
   var col_value=req.query.colvalue;
   var ord_value=req.query.ordervalue;
   var limiter=req.query.pager;
   var query={};
   var itemsPerPage=20;
   query[col_name]=col_value;
   console.log(col_name);
   console.log(col_value);
   console.log(query);
   console.log(limiter);
   console.log(ord_value);
   if (limiter== null)
   {
      limiter=1;
   }
   if (col_name== "" || col_value== "")
   {
     query={};
   }
   var skiper=itemsPerPage * (limiter-1);  

   users.distinct('symbol',function(e, syms){
      sub_users.find({order_id: ord_value},{},function(e,executions){   
        users.find(query,{skip:skiper,limit: itemsPerPage},function(e, docs){
           res.render('users', { 
              'usersSym':syms,
              'users': docs,
              'limit': limiter  ,
              'col':col_name,
              'opt':col_value,
              'exe':executions,
              'order_id':ord_value
           });
        });
     });
   });
});
```

> Here's the jquery on how to send post data:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
   $('body').on('click', '.button', function() {
      $("exe-scroll").dialog( "option", "width", 1000 );
      pid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
      document.getElementById('text').value =pid;
      var data={};
      data.col_name = $('#select').val();
      data.col_value = $('#selected').val();
      data.limiter =  $('#number').val();
      data.ord_value = $('#text').val();
      $.ajax({
         url:'http://localhost:3000/users', 
         type:'POST',
         dataType:'json',
         contentType: "application/json",
         data: JSON.stringify(data), 
         success: function (data) { 
            $( "#exe-scroll" ).dialog({ 
                maxWidth:600,
                maxHeight: 500,
                width: 700,
                height: 500,
                resizable:true,
                modal: true,
                close: function() {
                }
            });
        },
        error:
           function (data) {
               console.log('error');
            }
    });    
});  
</script>
```

[image: page element inspected]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to perform a `POST /users` but you don't have an appropriate route setup in express, you only have a `GET /users`.

Change your route in express to `router.post('/users', ...)` rather than `router.get('/users', ...)`.

---

Based on your comments, it would appear the actual problem isn't that your AJAX call is failing but more to do with the fact you are looking for the POSTed data in the wrong location. `req.query` represents the query string of the URL, in your case the data is sent up in the `body` therefore you need to pull the data from there instead i.e.

```
var col_name = req.body.col_name;
var col_value = req.body.col_value;
var ord_value = req.body.ord_value;
...
console.log(col_name);
console.log(col_value);
console.log(ord_value);
```

Also, pay close attention to the names here, you are looking for `colname`/`colvalue` etc. when in fact the client is posting `col_name`/`col_value`.

Comment: Hi James .. That was typo .. I have another router router.post ,with the same content as that of router.get..

Comment: @sasidharan well unfortunately I can only answer based on what I can see, I suggest you edit your existing answer to show the correct route and in the meantime I will update my answer. Also, could you show a screenshot of what you mean by the AJAX call is being "skipped"?

Comment: I have added the screen shot.

Comment: @sasidharan ok so that doesn't really help, I thought you meant you were seeing some funny behaviour in the Network tab. The `$.ajax` call won't be being "skipped", the debugger will step over that entire block because it's treated as a single line. I am confident if you placed the breakpoint inside the success callback you would see a response.

Comment: I kept an alert inside the success callback but it dint alert. And when I click on button the values which i'm posting are going as undefined which i could see in the console. Attached the console screen shot

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be that you are reading your params as if they were a GET :

```
var col_name=req.query.colname;
var col_value=req.query.colvalue;
var ord_value=req.query.ordervalue;
var limiter=req.query.pager;
```

Can you try with this instead ?

```
var col_name=req.body.colname;
var col_value=req.body.colvalue;
var ord_value=req.body.ordervalue;
var limiter=req.body.pager;
```

NOTE : Please make sure you have configured the body-parser middleware :

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Comment: Still I'm getting as undefined .. from console....
undefined
undefined
{ undefined: undefined }
undefined
undefined
POST /users 200 54.324 ms - 20867

Comment: I have modified the answer, please check if you have the body-parser middleware

Comment: Yes i do have .. app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: @sasidharan see my answer, the problem is inconsistencies between your client side/server-side variable names.

Comment: I have added alert in both the success and error callbacks. Ajax call back fails and an alert from error callback is raised. No logs to understand why its failing . Appreciate your help.

Comment: @James I have rectified it .  I'm getting the values properly now . following is from the console. symbol
USD/INR
{ symbol: 'USD/INR' }
1
INDIGOT66119
POST /users 200 86.126 ms - 36666  ..But still the ajax callback is not successful .

Comment: @James . I found the problem but not sure how to get rid off it. response.render() is the problem i face. When i replace it with response.send() callback is successful. I need to use the result set to frame a html table , hence I'm using response.render()

Comment: @james , richardtz I made it working. thanks guys for your assistance